# Can $P(A \cap B)$ be computed as $P(A)*P(B|A)$ and vice versa in any example?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

Following Bayes example is taken from [here](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol6/conditional.html)

> A math teacher gave her class two tests. 25% of the class passed both
>   tests and 42% of the class passed the first test. What percent of
>   those who passed the first test also passed the second test?

The Bayes formula for this example is:

$P(S|F)$ = $\frac{P(S)*P(F|S)}{P(F)}$

Using the following formula:

$P(S \cap F)$ = $P(S)*P(F|S)$

the above formula can be rewritten to this:

$P(S|F)$ = $\frac{P(S \cap F)}{P(F)}$

after assigning proper numbers this can be computed and this is the result:

$P(S|F)$ = $\frac{0.25}{0.42} = 0.60$

My question is if is possible to compute also $P(S)$ and $P(F|S)$ (as a compounds of $P(S \cap F)$) when $P(S|F)$ is known already?

Comment: PS: Can I somewhere find the documentation or cheat sheet for stackexchange equation editor?

Comment: Don't know about stats.SE but there is a very useful [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/15941) over on meta.math.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know only P(S|F) and P(F), you can't definetely compute P(S) and P(F|S). 
Lets use your example: we have P(S|F)=0.6 and P(F)=0.42. 
Here we have Solution1: P(S) = 0.5, P(F|S) = 0.5 fits. But Solution2: P(S) = 0.25, P(F|S) = 1 fits as well.
So the only thing you can tell is that P(S∩F) = 0.25 but you can't definetely compute P(S) and P(F|S) from this inputs.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to somehow extend the assignment so the P(S) and P(F|S) will be computable?

Comment: Yes, now you have 2 variables only one equation for it. To solve variables, you have to add another equation. For example, this could be done by determining P(S U F). Given P(S U F) = 0.67 you can solve for P(S) = P(S U F) - P(S) - P(S∩F) = 0.5. Then you have P(F|S) = P(S∩F)/P(S) = 0.5.